# How do I programmatically get the current default easing function in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, easing, jquery-easing

`$.easing` contains the built-in easing functions, but it doesn't seem to contain any information on which one is the current default (i.e. the one that is used if an easing function is not explicitly specified). `$.speed()` has an `easing` property which is `undefined` when I run it.

Comment: The default is swing. the only other option in the core is linear.

Comment: Comes from this line of the jQuery code... if you don't specify an easing in the options it defaults to the string 'swing': `opt.animatedProperties[name] = opt.specialEasing && opt.specialEasing[name] || opt.easing || 'swing';`